# Removing rows containing duplicate combination of values across columns in R

Tags: r, duplicates, subset

I have the following data frame:

```
     Player_1     Player_2    Player_3    Player_4        Player_5    Player_6      Player_7       total_sal
1   Mike Reilly Andrew Harris   RB 1    Dominque Rhymes Duron Carter    BC D    Shaquille Johnson   39084
2   Mike Reilly Andrew Harris   RB 1    Dominque Rhymes Shaquille Johnson   BC D    Duron Carter    39084
3   Mike Reilly Andrew Harris   RB 1    Duron Carter    Shaquille Johnson   BC D    Dominque Rhymes 39084
4   Mike Reilly Andrew Harris   RB 2    Dominque Rhymes Duron Carter    BC D    Shaquille Johnson   39084
5   Mike Reilly Andrew Harris   RB 2    Dominque Rhymes Shaquille Johnson   BC D    Duron Carter    39084
6   Mike Reilly Andrew Harris   RB 2    Duron Carter    Shaquille Johnson   BC D    Dominque Rhymes 39084
```

I am concerned with columns Player_1 through Player_7. I would like to remove rows in the data frame where the same combination of players shows up in these  columns. For example, in the above, rows 1 through 3 shows the same combination of players in different columns as does rows 4 through 6. I'm wondering if there's a way to detect and remove these duplicate rows, such that in the example above, the final data frame would only have one occurrence of rows 1-3 and one occurrence of 4-6 (it doesn't matter which one).

Data used:

```
structure(list(X = c(29L, 32L, 34L, 44L, 47L, 49L), Player_1 = c("Mike Reilly", 
"Mike Reilly", "Mike Reilly", "Mike Reilly", "Mike Reilly", "Mike Reilly"
), Player_2 = c("Andrew Harris", "Andrew Harris", "Andrew Harris", 
"Andrew Harris", "Andrew Harris", "Andrew Harris"), Player_3 = c("RB 1", 
"RB 1", "RB 1", "RB 2", "RB 2", "RB 2"), Player_4 = c("Dominque Rhymes", 
"Dominque Rhymes", "Duron Carter", "Dominque Rhymes", "Dominque Rhymes", 
"Duron Carter"), Player_5 = c("Duron Carter", "Shaquille Johnson", 
"Shaquille Johnson", "Duron Carter", "Shaquille Johnson", "Shaquille Johnson"
), Player_6 = c("BC D", "BC D", "BC D", "BC D", "BC D", "BC D"
), Player_7 = c("Shaquille Johnson", "Duron Carter", "Dominque Rhymes", 
"Shaquille Johnson", "Duron Carter", "Dominque Rhymes"), total_sal = c(39084L, 
39084L, 39084L, 39084L, 39084L, 39084L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `dat[!duplicated(t(apply(dat[1:7], 1, sort))),]`

Comment: In the `dput`, you also had `X` column at the beginning.  So you may need `dat[2:8]` instead of `dat[1:7]`